# Foreign Key Constraint in FMDB using swift in xcode , db error: table cannot find column

Tags: swift, swift3

```
func createdata(){ 
        if db.open()
        {
            let querySQL_floor = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FLOORDETAILS (floorid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,floorname TEXT NOT NULL )"
            db.executeStatements(querySQL_floor)
            let querySQL_room = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ROOMDETAILS (roomid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,roomname TEXT NOT NULL, capacity INTEGER NOT NULL, type TEXT NOT NULL, projector_available TEXT NOT NULL, floor_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(floor_id) REFERENCES FLOORDETAILS(floorid))"
              db.executeStatements(querySQL_room)
            NSLog("Table created")
            }   
}

func insert data(){
let roombookingDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
        if (roombookingDB?.open())! {
          let insertSQL_floor = "INSERT INTO FLOORDETAILS (floorid,floorname) VALUES (1,'Ground'), (2,'First'), (3,'Second'), (4,'Third')"
           roombookingDB?.executeUpdate(insertSQL_floor, withArgumentsIn: nil)
            let insertSQL_room = "INSERT INTO ROOMDETAILS (roomid,roomname,capacity,type,projector_available,floorid) VALUES (1,'BoardRoom', 10, 'Conference Room', 'Projector Available',1)"
            roombookingDB?.executeUpdate(insertSQL_room, withArgumentsIn: nil)
        }
}
```

How to solve this problem:

> Error: DB Error: 1 "table ROOMDETAILS has no column named floorid"

Comment: Refer : http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_8_Application_using_Swift_and_FMDB , If you Still confuse comment to me.